# OnStartPage CurrentPageNumber is wrong ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

i'm new using ITextSharp, and i'm trying to use the `OnStartPage` event method of `PdfPageEventHelper` to create a simple content table

Everything is almost done, the only issue is that the first call to `OnStartPage` the `PdfWriter` `CurrentPageNumber` is wrong, it should be 1 but is 2, then, all the other in all the other calls, the `CurrentPageNumber` are in the page it should be.

This is my code

```
public class MyPdfEventHandler: PdfPageEventHelper
{        
    protected List<PageIndex> Indice = new List<PageIndex>();
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PageIndex pi = new PageIndex
        {
            Page = writer.CurrentPageNumber,
            Name = "Name Example",
            Text = "Text Example"
        }        
        Indice.Add(pi);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer clarify "Why is this happening? Am i doing something wrong?"

Comment: @mkl totally, i forgot accept the answer, i'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

I created the following event listener:

```
public class OnStartPageTestHandler : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnStartPage - PdfWriter {0}, Document {1}", writer.CurrentPageNumber, document.PageNumber);
    }
}
```

and used it in the following test method

```
public void TestOnStartPagePageNumber()
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        writer.PageEvent = new OnStartPageTestHandler();
        document.Open();

        for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."));
        }
    }
}
```

and got this result:

```
OnStartPage - PdfWriter 1, Document 1
OnStartPage - PdfWriter 2, Document 2
OnStartPage - PdfWriter 3, Document 3
```

Thus, both the `PdfWriter` and the `Document` return the correct current page number.

---

For the test I used the current iText(Sharp) v5.5.13. If you happen to use an older version, please update, probably you deal with a bug fixed for a long time...